# Java Play Framework flow

Tags: java, html, playframework

I am beginner at java play `framework` and I have a trouble with it's working logic.

I created a new project with **activator new** and I'm working on its default format. When I start the project on `localhost:9000` it's working.

First, controllers become active then specific functions`(HomeController.index() or CountController.count())` starts. I can not see the connection between which `HTML` files, which are under views package, should be use.

**How can the program understand specifically which HTML file use by calling controllers function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the play framework, there is a routes file in the /conf directory, where the url is mapped to the controller. For example, in your routes file, there is a map like this

```
GET /index        controller.index()
```

when you type the following url in browser

```
localhost:9000/index
```

the play framework will map the '/index' to the controller index(). Then you can handle the request with the help of index() controller, which can return an html with specified path to the browser.

```
public static class index() extends Controller {
    return Ok(views.html.index);
}
```

This above is that how the play framework returns an html.

Good luck

Comment: Thanx your answering. I know the route logic but I wonder how the controller.index() knows the use which html templates which under the views. Should I add index.html or if my route has "GET /asd    controller.tst()" should I add tst.html or anything like that

Comment: @ets10, in the controller, the html file can be selected as you want, if you want to return index.html in the controller.tsx(), it's ok. but ,you should specify the path of returned html templates.

Comment: thanx this helps me a lot.